# Correct way to expect/receive state with Enzyme & MockProvider

Tags: graphql, enzyme, react-apollo

I'm testing a component that is using a graphql useLazyQuery. MockProvider is provided by the Apollo recommended library @apollo/react-testing. I want to test that a certain message is being rendered base off the length of the data that is returned from the query. I have html elements structured like this:

```
<div className="message" data-id={props.data ? props.data.specials.length > 0 ? 'valid' : 'invalid' : ''}>
    ...children
</div>
```

I read through Apollo's docs about testing and wrote up a test like this:

```
mock = {
    request: {
        query: GET_PRODUCTS,
        variables: { zip: "91001" }
    },
    result: {
        data: { 
            specials: [
                {
                    "_id": "5ecf28c459d3781a2e99738e",
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ecf28c459d3781a2e99738f",
                }
            ] 
       }
   }
}

wrapper = mount(
    <MockedProvider mocks={[mock]} addTypename={false}>
        <Store.Provider value={[{ loading: false, zip: null }]}>
            <GetZipCode />
        </Store.Provider>
    </MockedProvider>
)

await wait(0)

expect(wrapper.find(message).prop('data-id')).toEqual('valid')
```

But I've found that the tests do not update based on the mock that I put it. I have a test about this where I'm passing this value as the mock:

```
mock = {
    request: {
        query: GET_PRODUCTS,
        variables: { zip: "32005" }
    },
    result: {
        data: { specials: [] }
    }
}

...after tests
expect(wrapper.find(message).prop('data-id')).toEqual('invalid')
```

And for both of these tests the expected value is "" which is the initial value for my data-id prop in my html element. If I were to set the initial value to "invalid" compared to "" then the expected value in my test would output "invalid".

It seems that no matter what I passed my mock provider it doesn't wait for it to be passed. I'm using the wait package that Apollo recommends as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna mock using jest, you use the following approach

```
jest.mock("apollo-client", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  useQuery: (query: any) => {
    //other mocks if needed
  },
  useLazyQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([
    jest.fn(),
    {
      data: {
        yourProperties: "Add Here",
      },
      loading: false,
    },
  ]),
}));
```

As you see, this approach even returns the mock function that is called in the code to be tested.

Answer (score -1):

I faced in similar issues while testing with useLazyQuery. I would suggest writing a custom hook on top of useLazyQuery. This will have two benefits:

1. No need to wrap your test instance in Mock provider. You can mock the entire module (custom hook) using jest and use mockReturnValue method to simulate different behaviours (loading, data, error)
2. You can easily switch between actual query or some mock data in local file system while development.

Refer this [blog](https://medium.com/@achal41/react-with-graphql-a-better-way-e0a48664d846) for implementation details and demo app.